# change selected object value in an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So I have 2 arrays of objects. The first one is the main data and the second one is the filtered data.

```
main = [
{id:1,type:normal,qty:10,number:111},
{id:2,type:special,qty:10,number:222},
{id:3,type:normal,qty:10,number:333},
{id:4,type:normal,qty:10,number:111},
]
dispatch({ type: "MAIN_DATA", payload: main});

filter = main.filter((data) => {
      return data.number === state.number;
    }); 
dispatch({ type: "SPECIAL_DATA", payload: filter });
```

I only want to take data that has the same number as the `state.number` and then assign it to a new array of state. In this case, it matched with `number:111`.

```
const initialState = {
    mainData: [],
    filterData: [],
    finalData:[],
    number: 111
  };
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
```

So far there is no problem with the code. But when I reassigned a value from the `filterData` and `concat` both arrays, all of the values changed.

```
if (state.filterData) {
   const data = state.filterData.filter((data) => {
   return (data.type = "special");
   }); 
}
dispatch({type: "FINAL_DATA",
payload: state.mainData.concat(state.receiveData)});
```

At first, I thought it's because of the `concat` but it wasn't. The problem is, all of the values from `type` key got replaced by `special`.

```
[
{id:1,type:special,qty:10,number:111},
{id:2,type:special,qty:20,number:222},
{id:3,type:special,qty:30,number:333},
{id:4,type:special,qty:10,number:111},
]
```

What I want to achieve is this

```
[
{id:1,type:special,qty:10,number:111},
{id:2,type:special,qty:20,number:222},
{id:3,type:normal,qty:30,number:333},
{id:4,type:special,qty:10,number:111},
]
```

Could someone tell me what is the problem with my code? Because I think I didn't do any changes with the original data, but how come it turned out like this?

Appreciate any kinda helps. thanks before

Answer (score 0):

```
if (state.filterData) {
  const data = state.filterData.filter((data) => {
   return (data.type = "special");
  }); 
}
```

in the above code, you are assigning "special" in data.type using assignment operator(=). Use comparison operator(== / ===) instead of assignment(=)

Solution -

```
   data.type === "special"
```

Comment: it's not working, the value is still the same. I need to assign a new value.

Comment: replaced data.type = "special" with data.type === "special"?

Comment: Then another component or function is also changing in the same reference of the array objects. And that code you didn't mention in the example.